# Kohana 3 redirection on non-standard ports

Tags: php, redirect, kohana, kohana-3

I am having problems using Kohana3.

Currently on development we use port 444 for https.

If I redirect while I am on

```
https://localhost:444 

$this->request->redirect('/login');
```

I will be sent to

```
http://localhost
```

I google quite a lot and found that Kohana3 was (very) buggy regarding redirects and applied all the fixes, still the error keeps happening.

Also, I tried to hack the code and force always https (as a test), then the problem was that i got redirected to

```
https://localhost/login
```

which does not exists as I run the server on port 444 rather than 443.

So I am pretty much out of ideas, seems that neither the protocol nor the port are properly detected by kohana...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your `base_url` properly in `bootstrap.php`. Kohana doesn't "detect" anything.